# Content removal with Http response of 200

Tags: google-image-search, google-cache, dmca

in these days I find out that an image hosting service called pixroute.com has a strange behavior when notified with a DMCA notice.

It basically replace the content with a placeholder image but the http response is still 200.

This means with the google removal tool I am unable to clear the cache of google images search engine.

Anyone got any Idea how to deal with this ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: How long has it been? If your page is gone and there is no link, I would suspect that the image would be removed though it could take time. Search engines are notoriously slow. It may take months.

Comment: It's a week or so. But the Image was used on a Forum to redirect to stolen material. I submitted the forum page to reclaw, If this will lead to a solution i will notify it.

Comment: It will likely take more time than a couple of weeks. You cannot hurry up Google no matter how much you want to or thing you have. ;-) It is like pushing an elephant! Push too hard and you may regret it. It will likely take a month or two.

Comment: If it's a DMCA issue, you may be able to submit a DMCA removal request to Google too. If it's just an image that was "removed", then it'll take quite some time to recrawl & reindex it (I'd recommend encouraging them to just use a 404 instead).

Answer (score 1):

As long as pixroute.com is not returning a 404 not found or 410 gone error when trying to access the image then Google will not remove it from the index as the crawler doesn't realise that the image is gone. Unfortunately there is nothing you can really do about this as it depends on pixroute.com applying a change to the application code to return a 410 gone error even if the placerholder image is still returned so that the Googlebot knows that the image is gone and the link is no longer valid and never will be again.